# Integration of LegendreP

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am trying to integrate a product of 2 Legendre polynomials as follows:

```
Integrate[LegendreP[1, x] LegendreP[2l+1, x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

I get the result:

```
Sin[2 l \[Pi]]/(l (3 + 2 l) \[Pi])
```

which is always 0 for integer values of `l`, but shouldn't the result be 0 for $2l+1\neq1$ and 2/3 for $2l+1=1$, since the `LegendreP` are orthogonal?

Comment: To evaluate definite integrals depending on a parameter at a value for the parameter, it is more reliable to use `Limit` as some answers below show. This is sometimes described in terms of "generic" results. Many times it corresponds to the limitations of our notation.  For instance, in results that have `Sin[]` of the parameter (as in your case), replacing `Sin[]` by `Sinc[]` via `Sin -> (# Sinc[#] &)` often gives a result valid for all values of the parameter. Note `Limit[ans, l -> value]` does not take a lot of time when `ans` is continuous, though it is slower than direct substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Look at

```
Table[Sin[2 l \[Pi]]/(l (3 + 2 l) \[Pi]), {l, -2, 2}]
```

and then try

```
Limit[Sin[2 l \[Pi]]/(l (3 + 2 l) \[Pi]), l -> 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Assumptions` by hand or calculate the `Limit`

```
Integrate[LegendreP[1, x] LegendreP[2 l + 1, x], {x, -1, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> l == 0]
Limit[Integrate[LegendreP[1, x] LegendreP[2 l + 1, x], {x, -1, 1}], 
 l -> 0]
Integrate[LegendreP[1, x] LegendreP[2 l + 1, x], {x, -1, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> 3 + 2 l == 0]
Limit[Integrate[LegendreP[1, x] LegendreP[2 l + 1, x], {x, -1, 1}], 
 l -> -(3/2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) to handle the special case.

```
f[l_, x_] = 
 Piecewise[{{Integrate[LegendreP[1, x] LegendreP[2 l + 1, x], {x, -1, 1}], 
    ll != 0}, {Integrate[LegendreP[1, x] LegendreP[1, x], {x, -1, 1}], 
    l == 0}}]
```

[image]

```
Simplify[f[l, x], Element[l, Integers] && l != 0]

(* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that sometimes a general result is returned. Think of:

```
Integrate[x^p,x]
```

returns:

```
x^(1+p)/(1+p)
```

However,

```
Integrate[x^-1, x]
```

gives:

```
Log[x]
```

But that is not represented by the general result…