# How to integrate Legendre polynomials with parameters?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

The orthogonality of Legendre polynomials:

$\int_{-1}^1 \mathrm{P}_l(x) \mathrm{P}_k(x) \mathrm{d} x=0, \quad k \neq l$

But

```
Integrate[LegendreP[l, x]*LegendreP[k, x], {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> Element[{l, k}, PositiveIntegers] && l != k]

(* Integrate[LegendreP[k, x] LegendreP[l, x], {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> (l | k) \[Element] Integers && l > 0 && k > 0 && l != k] *)
```

How should I write the code? Thanks!

Comment: Is [253675](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253675/proof-associated-legendre-polynomials-are-orthogonal-integral-doesnt-solve) helpful?

Comment: I have seen this question and some related questions, which do not involve zero, so this is the content of my question. @Syed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

int[k_Integer, k_Integer] := int[k, k] =
  Integrate[LegendreP[k, x]^2, {x, -1, 1}]

int[k_Integer, l_Integer] := int[k, l] =
  Integrate[LegendreP[k, x]*LegendreP[l, x], {x, -1, 1}]

Table[int[k, l], {k, -3, 3}, {l, -3, 3}] //
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings ->
    {Range[-3, 3], Range[-3, 3]}] &
```

[image]

For non-negative integers,

```
FindSequenceFunction[
  Table[{k, int[k, k]}, {k, 0, 3}], k] // Simplify

(* 2/(1 + 2 k) *)
```

Verifying outside of the range used in the `FindSequenceFunction`

```
And @@ Table[int[k, k] == 2/(2 k + 1), {k, 0, 50}]

(* True *)
```

Similarly for negative integers,

```
FindSequenceFunction[
  Table[{k, int[k, k]}, {k, -5, -1}], k] // Simplify

(* -(2/(1 + 2 k)) *)

And @@ Table[int[k, k] == -2/(2 k + 1), {k, -50, -1}]

(* True *)
```

Off the main diagonal,

```
FindSequenceFunction[
  Table[{k, int[k, -k - 1]}, {k, 0, 5}], k] // Simplify

(* 2/(1 + 2 k) *)

And @@ Table[int[k, -k - 1] == 2/(2 k + 1), {k, 0, 50}]

(* True *)
```

and,

```
FindSequenceFunction[
  Table[{k, int[k, -k - 1]}, {k, -5, -1}], k] // Simplify

(* -(2/(1 + 2 k)) *)

And @@ Table[int[k, -k - 1] == -2/(2 k + 1), {k, -50, -1}]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems that without using mathematical methods and only utilizing MMA code, it's impossible to obtain results directly by symbolically integrating the parameterized Legendre functions. Instead, the conclusion can only be reached through enumeration by adopting an assignment-based approach.